# There's a nice 3D graph in the help file of the Plot3D function. How can I reproduce it?

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d, plot-themes

I find the two graphs (see below) in `Plot3D`'s help page elegant and appealing. How can I reproduce it? I read the whole help page but didn't find how the graphs were made.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Surely there are plenty of examples on the `Plot3D` page. What exactly are you having difficulty with? The color scheme, mesh lines, labeling? Please be more specific. Thanks.

Comment: I agree that WRI should include code used to generate these plots. But you can always do this: simply copy the image from the help page and paste it into your open notebook and give it a name. say `p`. Now do `myopts = AbsoluteOptions[p]` which gives you all options used to generate the plot. But without knowing the function used it is hard to make progress. Here is screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aizJj.png)  you can now use same options in your Plot3D command.

Comment: @Nasser Interesting, `Boxed` can be used to draw specific faces of the box... which is an undocumented feature.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When all else fails you can construct graphics explicitly using `Show`, `Graphics3D` and `Plot3D`:

```
Show[
 Graphics3D[
  {Line[
    {{{-3.5, -3.5, -2}, {-3.5, 3.5, -2}, {3.5, 
       3.5, -2}, {3.5, -3.5, -2}, {-3.5, -3.5, -2},
      {-3.5, -3.5, 2}, {-3.5, 3.5, 2}, {3.5, 3.5, 2}, {3.5, 
       3.5, -2}},
     {{-3.5, 3.5, 2}, {-3.5, 3.5, -2}}}],
   Dashing[1/50],
   Line[{{0, 0, -2}, {0, 0, -Sin[-1/2]}}],
   PointSize[Large],
   Point[{0, 0, -Sin[-1/2]}],
   Line[{{3.5, 0, -2}, {0, 0, -2}, {0, -3.5, -2}}],
   Text[f[x, y], {0, 0, -Sin[-1/2]}, {0, -1.5}],
   Text[x, {0, -3.5, -2}, {1, 1}],
   Text[y, {3.5, 0, -2}, {-2, 1}],
   Text[z, {-3.5, -3.5, 0}, {2, 0}],
   Text[reg, {1.7, -1.7, -2}]},
  BaseStyle -> {16, Bold, Italic, FontFamily -> "Times"},
  Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> {1, -2, 1.5}],
 Plot3D[{-Sin[x] - Sin[y - 1/2], -2.001},
  {x, y} \[Element] Disk[{0, 0}, Pi],
  PlotStyle -> {RGBColor[{0.75, 0.75, 1, 0.6}], White},
  BoundaryStyle -> None,
  Lighting -> "Accent",
  Mesh -> 5, PlotPoints -> 50, MeshStyle -> White]]
```

[image]

Here `Graphics3D` constructs the sides of the box we want, dashed lines, the point on the surface, and places text (styled with `BaseStyle`) at relevant offset directions from specific points.

`Plot3D` takes care of the actual surface, the plotting region (including the "shadow" under it) and their styling and lighting. If you don't want a partially drawn box or other extra annotations you can just use `Plot3D` part and remove the rest.